# Trouble downloading packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, source-packages

When I try to download any of the following package, it shows error.

```
sudo apt-get install libelf-dev
sudo apt-get install tcl-dev
sudo apt-get install tk-dev


Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package tk-dev
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `apt-get install` Unable to locate package, It means that package you are installing may not available on PPA according to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Then You should add appropriate PPA (For Finding PPA Refer Website: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppas)

Then `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install [pkg-name]`

For More Information About How To Add PPAs Visit: [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Comment: I had ubuntu installed on VMWare workstation, inspite of everything I tried the packages couldn't be found. I just dual booted my system and now the packages got installed.